# Create blob url with javascript

Tags: javascript, video, blob

I'm trying to create a web application for videos, I decided to start by configuring the videos, in case of problem, creating blob url for videos.
It turns out that I'm not sure what terms to use to search in google and the ones I used do not find anything very simple or straightforward.
I would like to know how I can create a blob url for videos and what would be the best way, since I have already seen topics using FileReader and MediaSource and some others, so I would like to know the simplest way to do this.

I'm testing on a direct html, without external libraries or external files.

```
var URL = this.window.URL || this.window.webkitURL;
        var file = new Blob(["http://localhost/assets/mp4/video.mp4"],{"type" : "video\/mp4"});
        var value = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#MyVideo').attr('src',value);
        });
```

Generates a blob link but does not load the video

### Edit:

For further questions from beginners like me, I got the expected result with the script below:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/assets/mp4/video.mp4');
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e){
    var blob = new Blob(([xhr.response]));
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.getElementById('_video').src = url;
};
```

Comment: `new Blob(["http://localhost/assets/mp4/video.mp4"]` creates a blob that contains the string `http://localhost/assets/mp4/video.mp4`, Non the contents of a file at at location. A blob will not download anything. Why to you want to use a blob anyway? just set `src=`

Comment: I have a possible answer for you but it uses `FileReader` or `XMLHTTPRequest` since you need to fill the blob with an **Array** of bytes. Let me know if you're interested and I'll type an example...